# R 3.5.2 version: Rmysql or pool or devtools package not found

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

I am using R version `3.5.2` and I need to use mysql table with my UI in shiny app.

I found packages like `DBI`, `pool`, and `Rmysql` they are not available for the version of R I’m using.

Are there any alternative packages that allow me to use a mysql table?

Comment: I checked a few of these packages on CRAN and they only seem to require R >3.0.0. Are you sure you tried installing them correctly? Which CRAN mirror did you use? What error message did you get exactly? Why can't you updated your R version?

Comment: Yes all the packages do show >3... I tried install.packages(c(‘devtools’, repos=‘http://cran.studio.com/‘)

install. packages("devtools")


```

> install.packages('RMySQL', repos='https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘RMySQL’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3) 
> 
```

Comment: Well, it should look more like `install.packages("devtools", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com/")` Seems like this is just a typo.

Comment: Why are you installing `RMySQL` from that particular mirror? Why not just use the https://cran.rstudio.com/ as well? It's possible that some mirrors might not be up to date.

Comment: I tried the above line...


> install.packages('devtools', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
> 
> 
Warning message:
package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

Comment: I tried with cran and because I got the error in installation, was looking for alternative and found that as one of the solution so tried

Comment: I am using a docker image for a tool an directly pulling it from dockerhub, so the R version by default and required is 3.5.3..

Comment: Is that computer connected to the internet? Can you bring up the URL https://cran.rstudio.com/ in a web browser on that machine? It sounds like there might be some network setting on your end that's blocking the connection to the CRAN server.

Comment: I can go to cran.rstudio.com and https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES

Comment: And you are not running R on a different computer or server? I mean you mentioned docker so it's unclear to me if you are talking about accessing that site from within the docker container or just on your computer in general.